# Performance in Java between using obj.getXY() and Object o = obj.getXY()

Tags: java, android, performance, reference

The title might been misleading, but I can´t pack my question in one sentence.

Since I am developing for Android I worry much more about performance. And because of that, I thought about using

```
obj.getXY().doX(); 
obj.getXY().doY();
```

or

```
Object o = obj.getXY();
o.doX(); 
o.doY();
```

What is faster?
Making a reference to call all the methods or using always the getter?

Comment: Why don't you check yourself with a simple benchmark? I would guess the second way is slightly quicker, especially if the getter is a little more complicated than a simple return statement.

Comment: Even the crappy Android JVM is going to optimize away the difference between these two. Don't worry about it.

Comment: The ONLY reason you should worry about this kind of thing is if you have profiled your app, and the profile has identified the methods that do this as worthy of micro-optimization.  Micro-optimizing code that is "hardly ever" run is a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the second may be a little faster in Android versions before 2.3. 
Here it is even beneficial to not have getters at all and directly do

```
obj.xy.doX();
```

or

```
Object o = obj.xy;
o.doX();
o.doY();
```

See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#internal_get_set)

Answer (score 3):

The first variant will never be faster than the second, it's equal to

```
{Object tmp = obj.getXY(); tmp.doX();}
{Object tmp = obj.getXY(); tmp.doY();}
```

If `getXY()` is trivial (for example just returning a constant) and final, good compilers will optimize the double call away. In all other cases, an extra method call will make it slower.

Since the second version is more readable anyway, I'd go with it. But, as pointed out by others, unless `getXY()` is complex, this kind of micro optimization will not have a noticeable impact on the performance of your program.

Just **tested** it (`doX()`/`doY()` are no-ops, OpenJDK6 on x64):

`Integer getXY(){return 42;}`: No noticable difference
`Integer getXY(){return Integer.valueOf("42");}`: Variant two about twice as fast, as is to be expected.